# Managing Database Calls For Every Socket Message Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, webrtc, spring-websocket, signaling

I have a spring boot application web-socket server up and running as a WEBRTC signaling server.

This server has to log some data to the database, based on the messages rotated from/to the server, via different client sockets.

While trying a conference call from client side using more than 2 peers, and running the signaling as debugger with breakpoints, the scenario was successfully completed and the database was updated as expected and the conference call took place.

But, if I run the server without debug and breakpoints, I get an sql error

```
Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: HikariProxyPreparedStatement@1623454983 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: 

delete from my_table where my_table_id='601cbe2b-6af2-4e82-a69c-52b92d30686c'; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: HikariProxyPreparedStatement@1623454983 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: 

delete from my_table where my_table_id='601cbe2b-6af2-4e82-a69c-52b92d30686c'
```

I am using Spring JPA and calling the save function on every message received by the web-socket after populating the entity data and all its nested lists and relational entity object, in order to keep data of the call flow.

```
conferenceRepository.save(conference);
```

I think the error is because of queries running concurrently on the database, in random order, while the data is still not there in the database to act upon.

As in debug mode, I am taking time to move from one breakpoint to another, and this is assuring the data persistence.

But I am not totally sure of the problem.

Is there an optimal way to apply concurrent database calls and updates and make sure the data is preserved and persisted properly in the database for concurrent web-socket related messages?

Comment: can you share the `Conference` class, is it that you create a new `Conference` object each time or are you updating an existing one with the messages?